# MySQLi prepared statements inserting zero

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make a mysqli prepared statement, and for some reason, at the very least, strings are being turned into 0's (zeros).

Example:
**Table**

```
id - int, PK  
name - varchar(45)
```

**Code**

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES(?)")){
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$name);
    $name="Test1";
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    echo "prepare failed";
}
```

If I run this, the newly inserted row in the table will have 0 for the name. What am I doing wrong? I can't use PDO because the server this is going on doesn't have it available.

Comment: You need to declare `$name` *before* using it, for one.

Comment: Put `$name="Test1";` before `bind_param()`

Comment: @coreno i think your problem is elsewhere. maybe in how youre later retrieving the rows. Consider making a short/minimal fully self contained script(create table + insert then select) which can be run and will demonstrate the problem. likely, you'll discover the issue in the process of making that script.

Comment: @ceejayoz @furas bind_param() takes a `reference variable`. Its perfectly fine how its coded now.

Answer (score -2):

There are few wrong things on your code :

- bind_param doesn't exist on PDOStatement, but bindParam yes.
- when binding param using names you have to put ":" before the param into your query.
- if you are using ? use indexes numbers.
- this is optional but you should pass the param type using the PDO consts such PDO::PARAM_STR for strings.
- Finally you're defining your $name var after using it, that won't work: you have to define the var before using her.

**Code**

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES(:name)")){
    # defining $name
    $name = "Test1";

    # putting $name to the param :name
    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    # executing the prepared query.
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    echo "prepare failed";
}
```

Comment: i imagine $mysqli means mysqli extension, not pdo.

Comment: yeah, i haven't noticed that, but why using mysqli when we can use PDO who's supporting 12 different SQL drivers ?

Comment: mysqli has some features pdo doesnt. plus, you dont always have a choice(existing code).